# tabbed activity fragments swipe unlock if button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I made a tabbed activity with two fragments and i want the activity to be locked at fragment1 unless the user click a button in fragment1 then the activity switch to fragment2 automatically and the swipe is unlocked so you can switch between fragment1 and fragment2. I have been learning java for a week now and creating this tow fragment takes me a lot of effort and headache and since i have not studied java or other programming languages i think i can't figure this one on my own please help me.

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple. If you want to work it with a button, add button inside the tab, and at Onclick View call the 2nd fragment method.